# Getting "Not available for deploy for this organization" when creating a package version with translations. Is there a particular reason?

Tags: metadata, translation, packaging-2, second-generation-packaging

I'm getting the following error running the command to create a new version of my package. In this version I just added the translations for Brazilian Portuguese.

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  pt_BR: Not available for deploy for this organization

The scratch org definition file is quite simple:

```
{
  "orgName": "Callout Company Co.",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": [],
  "language": "en_US",
  "settings": {
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableEndUserLanguages": true,
      "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    }
  }
}
```

No idea of what could be causing this issue. Translations and Custom Object Translations are two fully supported metadata types (as seen in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47)).